# After submit go back previous page with model pop up

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I got a problem is after I save and go back to index.php .the model pop up not working, how to make after save, will get pup out model after going back to index.php. Hope all pro can help me to solve this problem, tq.
This one is index.php
//This part is my model //

```
<form method="post" action="action.php">
<input type="text" name="username"/>
</form>
      <div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <div class="modal-title" style="padding-left: 18%;">
                <img style="width: 14%;" src="include/img/activation_page/logo.png">
                <img style="position: absolute; font-size: 20px;font-weight: 700; top: 15%; left: 30%;" src="include/img/memodise.png">
                <font style="font-size: 26px; font-weight: 300; position: absolute; top: 30%; left: 30%;">Log in</font>
                <font style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: 300; position: absolute; top: 60%; left: 30%;">Not a member? <span class="register1" id="register1">Register</span></font>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

//This one is my action.php//

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
 //save data to database//

 echo "<script>window.location='index.php'</script>";
<script>$('#loginModal').modal('show')</script>
}
```

Comment: You cannot move to another page, and then execute code in that page, in the same script. There are also syntax errors in your code.

Comment: got any other suggestion ?

Comment: Kiko is right - your best solution might be to pass a parameter into the URL to open then open the modal up

Comment: can i have the example , cos i dont sure how to write,tq

Comment: how are you submitting your form? Are you using jquery to submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(isset($_GET['return'])){

  echo "<script>$('#loginModal').modal('show')</script>";
}
```

Use the above snippet to show the model.

in your `action.php`

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
  //save data to database//

 echo "<script>window.location='index.php?return=1'</script>";
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: f(isset($__GET['return'])){

  <script>$('#loginModal').modal('show')</script>
}
This part of script where should i put , is it put under index.php ?

Comment: @LawrenceChong yess

Comment: levaral  it dont want to pup out >< But i try using Inspect element to run the script , it can pop up the model

Comment: @LawrenceChong you want to hide?

Comment: what mean by hide ?

Comment: @LawrenceChong popup is not shwing?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your index.php

```
<script>$('#loginModal').modal('show')</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `action.php`

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['login'])){ ?>
    <script>
        $('#loginModal').modal('show');
        $('#loginModal').on('hidden.bs.modal',function(){
            window.location = 'index.php';
        });
     </script>
<?php }?>
```